# Magic 1089 in Scheme using Dr. Racket

Tags: string, numbers, scheme, racket

I am trying to create a program that consumes xyz, with digits in decreasing order, and produces 1089. I have to take xyz, reverse the digits, determine the difference between xyz and it's reverse and call it diff, add diff and it's reverse and then get the answer of 1089. I've been trying for hours but I am unable to figure out how to create the code. So far I have an attempt with only functions but I still can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?:

1)

```
(define h 100)
(define t 10)
(define o 1)

(define (front xyz)
  (number->string (substring xyz 0 1)))

(define (mid xyz)
  (number->string (substring xyz 1 2)))

(define (back xyz)
  (number->string (substring xyz 2 3)))

(define (reversexyz xyz)
  (string->number (+ (* (back xyz) h) (* (mid xyz) t) (* (front xyz) o))))

(define (diff abc)
  (- xyz (reversexyz)))

(define (frontdiff abc)
  (number->string (substring frontdiff 0 1)))

(define (middiff abc)
  (number->string (substring middiff 1 2)))

(define (backdiff abc)
  (number->string (substring backdiff 2 3)))

(define (reversediff xyz)
  (number->string (+ (* (backdiff abc) h) (* (middiff abc) t) (* (frontdiff abc) o))))

(define (magic xyz)
  (+ diff reversediff))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this explanation](http://www.mathsisfun.com/1089.html) this should be as easy as:

```
(define (pad0 str) ; add leading 0's to a string, 3 characters wide
  (~a #:width 3 #:align 'right #:left-pad-string "0" str))

(define (reverse-num n) ; reverse a number
  (string->number (list->string (reverse (string->list (pad0 (number->string n)))))))

(define (magic xyz) ; the magic happens here
  (define diff (abs (- (reverse-num xyz) xyz)))
  (+ diff (reverse-num diff)))
```

Testing:

```
> (magic 123)
1089
> (magic 678)
1089
> (magic 321)
1089
> (magic 546)
1089
```

FWIW, after this modification, there are still 90 numbers between 100 and 999 (inclusive) where the algorithm doesn't work:

```
> (for/sum ((i (in-range 100 1000)) #:when (not (= (magic i) 1089))) 1)
90
```